# @grid-float-breakpoint: @screen-desktop; not working in bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, less, nav

I'm trying to adjust my nav in bootstrap so that it collapses at `992px` instead of `768px`. I'm perplexed as to why `@grid-float-breakpoint: @screen-desktop;` won't work. I've used it before in other projects plus everything I've read on stackoverflow has suggested that is the answer. I've even gone as far as changing the variable for `@grid-float-breakpoint` inside of bootstraps variables.less and compiled it using grunt and it still doesn't work. I also tried using `@screen-md-min` and still nothing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `@grid-float-breakpoint` using the [Bootstrap Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) worked as expected for me.

I know this seems obvious, but are you sure you changed your `<link/>` to point to the updated bootstrap CSS file and that your browser doesn't have the old version cached?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing OK

"The navbar collapses into its vertical mobile view when the viewport is narrower than @grid-float-breakpoint, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least @grid-float-breakpoint in width. Adjust this variable in the Less source to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value is 768px (the smallest "small" or "tablet" screen"

Could you have maybe a html error? A cache problem? Compiling old files?

Try to compile in http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and apply ot to your project to discard problems

Good luck :)